# How to securely store the amazon access token for Amazon KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms, key-management

I am exploring the amazon KMS managed service and it seems secure for storing the Master key and Data key. 
I am able to decrypt the data key as plain text from encrypted data key using AWS KMS API / CLI.

But I have one concern, to access the amazon KMS for decrypting the data key, I need to pass the access token and encrypted data key.

so Where can I securely store the amazon access token and encrypted data key?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: You can use Secret Manager to Store the tokens and to add additional layer of security you can encrypt that using KMS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to pass the access token and encrypted data key.

Indeed, you need authenticate and authorize the client before calling any AWS service.

Maybe you could elaborate what you mean by *amazon access token*. Actually you need to store access key and access secret and optionally a (temporary) session token to properly authorize the service. I assume under the "amazon access token" you mean the client credentials.

> Where can I securely store the amazon access token and encrypted data key?

For the data key - the encrypted data key may be stored/sent along the data (if you generate a new key for each encryption) or as a configuration (if you plan to reuse the key), that's already safely encrypted.

If your client (code using the KMS) is running on the AWS infrastructure, you may use **[service roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html)** to allow access from a service to the KMS service without storing the identity credentials explicitly. This is the default (and best) way if the client runs on AWS too.

If you are accessing the KMS services from outside AWS, you application needs to have the client credentials. As already commented, in theory you may use a Secret Manager as well, but then you need credentials to access that service anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update, To make it clear, I have a docker service running in AWS EC2 instance. Currently, I have the encrypted data key (received from the AWS KMS) in the application and, access key and access secret in a file. I would like to know Is there a secure way of keep the AWS credentials ?

Comment: @Harry if it's running on EC2 you may want to use the service roles and you don't need to store any credentials at all. However - when the client runs on a EC2-based docker, you need to [proxy](https://eng.lyft.com/scoping-aws-iam-roles-to-docker-containers-c9c5f8f2f75) calls to the metadata service. (Metadata service is an AWS endpoint how AWS SDK will get the service role credentials automatically when running on EC2) If you want to use credentials in your config file, then best option is to limit access to the config file (permissions, labels, ..)

Comment: Thanks, then what is the use of Access Secret Manager?

Comment: @Harry Secret Manager is intended to store credentials and sensitive configurations (for other, non-aws services), To access the secret manager you need to have the aws credentials or service roles too

Comment: Thanks @gusto2 You are making me so clear, Consider I have ECS Fargate where my container is deployed and I used AWS KMS for Master Key and Encrypted data key. From ECS Fargate (AWS Service) using Service-Linked Role, Will I be able to access AWS KMS without providing the AWS Access Key and Secret Key ?

Comment: @Harry Indeed, if you allow access to KMS in the [Task IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#enable_task_iam_roles), the SDK will be able to invoke KMS withpout explicit (provided) credentials. Fargate can assign a service role directly to the containers

Comment: I approved your answer, Thanks. So If my understanding is correct, I can store the encrypted data key from AWS KMS in the Amazon secret manager (instead of storing it in config file) and to access the amazon secret manager, I need to have service-linked role from AWS ECS to AWS secret manager for fetching the encrypted data key without credentials, Is it statement correct?

Comment: @Harry If you plan to use the secret manager, you may store the data key directly, you don't need to encrypt it by KMS again (Secret Manager will do that for you under the hood). However - generally you approach is correct

Comment: so which is the right approach - using only KMS for generating master and data key? Or using KMS for generating master key and data key with storing data key in secret manager? Or using only AWS secret manager for generating the master key and data key ?